# Exports NODEJS getting response as ''undefined''

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, export

I use the following code:

```
MYCODE.JS FILE:


function getName() {
  (async ()=>{
  let bodyapi = await axios.get(`www.API-EXAMPLE.com`)
  console.log("You've requested a number with the following ID: " + bodyapi.data.slice(14, 22));
  console.log("You've requested a number with the following NUMBER: " + bodyapi.data.slice(-11));
  const number = bodyapi.data.slice(-11);
  return number;
  })();
}
exports.getName = getName;
```

Then after exporting it I try using it.

```
MYAPP.JS FILE

const number = require('./requestnumber.js');


setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(number.getName());
}, 5000);
```

Console results:

```
undefined
You've requested a number with the following ID: MYID
You've requested a number with the following NUMBER: MYNUMBER
```

I want ''undefined'' to show as my number. When I console.log it on MYCODE.JS under the async, it shows the number I want, but when I try it out of the async or after exporting it, it shows as undefined.

Also, yes, I tried using `number.getname()` before `console.log`(g-ing) it, but I just can't manage to get it right. I tried 4 different ways, and I keep getting undefined. I don't know what to do, because the api takes around 1-2 seconds to get the number and ID, and it only works under the `async` on `MYCODE.js file`. Any ideas how I can do that without getting the exported number on my other file as `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mycode.js

```
async function getName() {
  let bodyapi = await axios.get(`www.API-EXAMPLE.com`)
  console.log("You've requested a number with the following ID: " + bodyapi.data.slice(14, 22));
  console.log("You've requested a number with the following NUMBER: " + bodyapi.data.slice(-11));
  const number = bodyapi.data.slice(-11);
  return number;
}

module.exports = getName;
```

MYAPP.JS FILE

```
const getName = require('./requestnumber.js');

(async() => {
  const number = await getName();
  console.log(number);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a anonymous function inside getName function 
That function is async. so getName func returns undefined before inner function returns. then inner function works. and print out console.
so  if you write

```
function getName() {
  let bodyapi = await axios.get(`www.API-EXAMPLE.com`)
  console.log("You've requested a number with the following ID: " + bodyapi.data.slice(14, 22));
  console.log("You've requested a number with the following NUMBER: " + bodyapi.data.slice(-11));
  const number = bodyapi.data.slice(-11);
  return number;
}
```